# How to substitute blanks between certain patterns using regex

Tags: java, regex, substitution

I want to substitute the blanks between the `$#` and the ending `#`.

Test String:

```
This is my variable A $#testpattern 1# and this is variable B $#testpattern 2 with multiple blanks#
```

Expected result:

```
This is my variable A $#testpattern1# and this is variable B $#testpattern2withmultipleblanks#
```

I got it to work when it only has one blank but with more than one it does not work.

Current Regex:

```
/(?<=\$#)(\w*?)(\s*?)(\w*?)(?=#)
```

Comment: @MrW It is tagged with java

Comment: This question is clear to answer. It has a language tag, and example string, desired outcome and a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java supports a finite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion, so you can add optional word characters or spaces to it `[\w\s]{0,100}` and for the lookahead you can add only `[\w\s]*` matching 1 or more whitespace characters in between.

```
(?<=\$#[\w\s]{0,100})\s+(?=[\w\s]*#)
```

For example

```
String string = "This is my variable A $#testpattern 1# and this is variable B $#testpattern 2 with multiple blanks#";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("(?<=\\$#[\\w\\s]{0,100})\\s+(?=[\\w\\s]*#)", ""));
```

Output

```
This is my variable A $#testpattern1# and this is variable B $#testpattern2withmultipleblanks#
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UiPBvy) and a [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A4pKts/1).

Comment: Thanks the fourth bird. This works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

- `\\$#(.*?)#` - capture string between delimiters
- find each capture group in the pattern.
- remove the blanks in that group.
- then in the original string, replace the captured string with the modified string.

```
String s = "This is my variable A $#testpattern 1# and this is variable B $#testpattern 2 with multiple blanks#";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$#(.*?)#");
Matcher m =p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    String str = m.group(1).replace(" ","");
    s = s.replace(m.group(1),str);
}
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
This is my variable A $#testpattern1# and this is variable B $#testpattern2withmultipleblanks#
```

Comment: Thanks WJS for your response.